# Pivot a table with one header row and one data row

Tags: sql, pivot

The attached code generates a simple table with one row and twelve columns. My goal is to pivot the end result to show 12 rows and two columns with each column headers `MX` and `Date`. I am new to SQL and just cannot make it happen this afternoon. Please help.

I have tried looking at multiple pivot examples but they all appear to demonstrate the opposite i.e converting rows into columns. Maybe i am new to this but i cannot imagine how the code would look like if it were the opposite. I am sure it is very easy; I just need to see it to learn it.

```
DECLARE @queryDate1 datetime SET @queryDate1 = '04/30/2017';
DECLARE @queryDate2 datetime set @queryDate2 = '03/31/2017';
DECLARE @queryDate3 datetime SET @queryDate3 = '04/30/2017';
DECLARE @queryDate4 datetime set @queryDate4 = '03/31/2017';
DECLARE @queryDate5 datetime SET @queryDate5 = '04/30/2017';
DECLARE @queryDate6 datetime set @queryDate6 = '03/31/2017';
DECLARE @queryDate7 datetime SET @queryDate7 = '04/30/2017';
DECLARE @queryDate8 datetime set @queryDate8 = '03/31/2017';
DECLARE @queryDate9 datetime SET @queryDate9 = '04/30/2017';
DECLARE @queryDate10 datetime set @queryDate10 = '03/31/2017';
DECLARE @queryDate11 datetime SET @queryDate11 = '04/30/2017';
DECLARE @queryDate12 datetime set @queryDate12 = '03/31/2017';


SELECT
     convert(varchar(10),@queryDate1,101) as [M1]
    ,convert(varchar(10),@queryDate2,101) as [M2]
    ,convert(varchar(10),@queryDate3,101) as [M3]
    ,convert(varchar(10),@queryDate4,101) as [M4]
    ,convert(varchar(10),@queryDate5,101) as [M5]
    ,convert(varchar(10),@queryDate6,101) as [M6]
    ,convert(varchar(10),@queryDate7,101) as [M7]
    ,convert(varchar(10),@queryDate8,101) as [M8]
    ,convert(varchar(10),@queryDate9,101) as [M9]
    ,convert(varchar(10),@queryDate10,101) as [M10]
    ,convert(varchar(10),@queryDate11,101) as [M11]
    ,convert(varchar(10),@queryDate12,101) as [M12]`
```

Actual resuls will be table with two columns. First column has a header of `MX` and the first record will be `M1`, second row will be `M2` and so on to `M12`.

The second column will be labeled as `Date` and the first record will be `04/30/2017`, second record will be `03/31/2017` and so on.

In summary, the table goes from 12 columns and 1 row to 12 rows and 2 columns (excluding the headers).

Comment: This can be done with `UNPIVOT`. But it might not be necessary if you're building the query like this. You could just do something like `SELECT [MX] = 'M1', [Date] = convert(varchar(10),@queryDate1,101) UNION ALL...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT 'M1' AS [MX], M1 AS [Date] FROM mytable
UNION ALL SELECT 'M2', M2 AS [Date] FROM mytable
UNION ALL SELECT 'M3', M3 AS [Date] FROM mytable
UNION ALL SELECT 'M4', M4 AS [Date] FROM mytable
--- and so on until M12
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=935ee449ad9c32a56c963a217d2728c7)**:

```
MX | Date      
:- | :---------
M1 | 04/30/2017
M2 | 03/31/2017
M3 | 04/30/2017
M4 | 03/31/2017
```

Comment: Works. Thank you much.

Comment: @BillSingh: welcome! If my answer properly responded to your question, please accept it by clicking the green check sign... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just generate the table that you want up-front:

```
select v.header,
       convert(varchar(10), v.dte, 101)
from (values (@queryDate1, 'M1'),
             (@queryDate2, 'M2'),
             (@queryDate3, 'M3'),
             . . .
     ) v(dte, header);
```